# Error trying to implement a mongoDB IO connector Sink

Tags: python, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

we started implementing a mongoDB IO Connector for first Apache Beam test, and the Source part seems to work properly. Concerning the Sink part, the execution leads to an error... We used this guidelines for the implementation: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-custom-io/

Our implementation can be found here: https://github.com/PEAT-AI/beam-extended

The example I try to run is the following:

```
"""
A simple example of how to use the MongoDB reader and writer.

If you like, you can test it out with these commands (requires Docker and
virtualenv for python2):

    $ virtualenv venv
    $ source venv/bin/activate
    $ pip install google-cloud-dataflow pymongo
    $ # The following line is optional if mongod is running already
    $ sudo service mongod stop
    $ docker run -p 27017:27017 --name dataflowtest --rm mongo:3.2
    $ docker exec -it dataflowtest mongo
    > use mydb
    > db.mycollection.insert({ _id: ObjectId() })
    > exit
    $ python -m simple
    $ # The following line is optional if mongod was shut down previously
    $ sudo service mongod start

"""

from __future__ import absolute_import

import logging

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

from beam_extended.io.mongodbio import ReadFromMongo, WriteToMongo


def transform_doc(document):
    print(document)
    return {'_id': str(document['_id'])}


def run(argv=None):
    """Main entry point; defines and runs the aggregation pipeline."""

    connection_string = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
    # Can also fetch a connection string from a Google Cloud Storage file.
    # This might be preferable to avoid pickling the mongodb connection string.
    # E.g.
    # connection_string = 'gs://my-bucket/mongo_connection_string.txt'
    # where "mongo_connection_string.txt" contains a single line with the connection string.

    # with beam.Pipeline(runner='DirectRunner', options=PipelineOptions()) as pipeline:
    options = PipelineOptions()
    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as pipeline:
        (pipeline
         | 'read' >> ReadFromMongo(connection_string, 'mydb', 'mycollection', query={}, projection=['_id'])
         | 'transform' >> beam.Map(transform_doc)
         | 'save' >> WriteToMongo(connection_string, 'mydb', 'mycollection'))
        #  | 'save' >> beam.io.WriteToText('./simple.txt'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

    run()
```

and I obtain the following stacktrace:

```
INFO:root:Missing pipeline option (runner). Executing pipeline using the default runner: DirectRunner.
INFO:beam_extended.io.mongodbio:Raw query: {}
INFO:beam_extended.io.mongodbio:Cleaned query: {}
INFO:beam_extended.io.mongodbio:Starting MongoDB read from mydb.mycollection with query {}
T4: <class 'beam_extended.io.mongodbio._MongoSink'>
INFO:dill:T4: <class 'beam_extended.io.mongodbio._MongoSink'>
# T4
INFO:dill:# T4
D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82fc9050>
INFO:dill:D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82fc9050>
T4: <class 'pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient'>
INFO:dill:T4: <class 'pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient'>
# T4
INFO:dill:# T4
D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82fc96e0>
INFO:dill:D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82fc96e0>
T4: <class 'pymongo.monitoring._EventListeners'>
INFO:dill:T4: <class 'pymongo.monitoring._EventListeners'>
# T4
INFO:dill:# T4
D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82fd5050>
INFO:dill:D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82fd5050>
# D2
INFO:dill:# D2
D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82f605c8>
INFO:dill:D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82f605c8>
# D2
INFO:dill:# D2
Lo: <thread.lock object at 0x7fdb8488aef0>
INFO:dill:Lo: <thread.lock object at 0x7fdb8488aef0>
F2: <function _create_lock at 0x7fdb875d57d0>
INFO:dill:F2: <function _create_lock at 0x7fdb875d57d0>
# F2
INFO:dill:# F2
# Lo
INFO:dill:# Lo
T4: <class 'pymongo.read_concern.ReadConcern'>
INFO:dill:T4: <class 'pymongo.read_concern.ReadConcern'>
# T4
INFO:dill:# T4
D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82fcae88>
INFO:dill:D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82fcae88>
# D2
INFO:dill:# D2
T4: <class 'pymongo.read_preferences.Primary'>
INFO:dill:T4: <class 'pymongo.read_preferences.Primary'>
# T4
INFO:dill:# T4
D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82f32910>
INFO:dill:D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82f32910>
# D2
INFO:dill:# D2
T4: <class 'pymongo.topology.Topology'>
INFO:dill:T4: <class 'pymongo.topology.Topology'>
# T4
INFO:dill:# T4
D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82fca7f8>
INFO:dill:D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82fca7f8>
T4: <class 'pymongo.client_session._ServerSessionPool'>
INFO:dill:T4: <class 'pymongo.client_session._ServerSessionPool'>
# T4
INFO:dill:# T4
D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82f43280>
INFO:dill:D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82f43280>
# D2
INFO:dill:# D2
D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82fc4e88>
INFO:dill:D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82fc4e88>
T4: <class 'pymongo.server.Server'>
INFO:dill:T4: <class 'pymongo.server.Server'>
# T4
INFO:dill:# T4
D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82fd05c8>
INFO:dill:D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82fd05c8>
T4: <class 'pymongo.server_description.ServerDescription'>
INFO:dill:T4: <class 'pymongo.server_description.ServerDescription'>
# T4
INFO:dill:# T4
D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82f327f8>
INFO:dill:D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82f327f8>
D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82fd3b40>
INFO:dill:D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82fd3b40>
# D2
INFO:dill:# D2
T4: <type 'set'>
INFO:dill:T4: <type 'set'>
# T4
INFO:dill:# T4
# D2
INFO:dill:# D2
C2: pymongo.pool.Pool
INFO:dill:C2: pymongo.pool.Pool
# C2
INFO:dill:# C2
D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82fcfa28>
INFO:dill:D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82fcfa28>
Lo: <thread.lock object at 0x7fdb8488afb0>
INFO:dill:Lo: <thread.lock object at 0x7fdb8488afb0>
# Lo
INFO:dill:# Lo
C2: pymongo.thread_util.BoundedSemaphore
INFO:dill:C2: pymongo.thread_util.BoundedSemaphore
# C2
INFO:dill:# C2
D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82f8c4b0>
INFO:dill:D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82f8c4b0>
T4: <class 'threading._Condition'>
INFO:dill:T4: <class 'threading._Condition'>
# T4
INFO:dill:# T4
D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82f8c398>
INFO:dill:D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82f8c398>
Lo: <thread.lock object at 0x7fdb8488afd0>
INFO:dill:Lo: <thread.lock object at 0x7fdb8488afd0>
# Lo
INFO:dill:# Lo
B3: <built-in method acquire of thread.lock object at 0x7fdb8488afd0>
INFO:dill:B3: <built-in method acquire of thread.lock object at 0x7fdb8488afd0>
F2: <function _get_attr at 0x7fdb875d5f50>
INFO:dill:F2: <function _get_attr at 0x7fdb875d5f50>
# F2
INFO:dill:# F2
# B3
INFO:dill:# B3
B3: <built-in method release of thread.lock object at 0x7fdb8488afd0>
INFO:dill:B3: <built-in method release of thread.lock object at 0x7fdb8488afd0>
# B3
INFO:dill:# B3
# D2
INFO:dill:# D2
# D2
INFO:dill:# D2
T4: <class 'pymongo.network.SocketChecker'>
INFO:dill:T4: <class 'pymongo.network.SocketChecker'>
# T4
INFO:dill:# T4
D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82f8c168>
INFO:dill:D2: <dict object at 0x7fdb82f8c168>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/beam_extended/examples/simple.py", line 62, in <module>
    run()
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/beam_extended/examples/simple.py", line 54, in run
    | 'save' >> WriteToMongo(connection_string, 'mydb', 'mycollection'))
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pvalue.py", line 111, in __or__
    return self.pipeline.apply(ptransform, self)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 458, in apply
    label or transform.label)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 468, in apply
    return self.apply(transform, pvalueish)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 504, in apply
    pvalueish_result = self.runner.apply(transform, pvalueish)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 193, in apply
    return m(transform, input)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 199, in apply_PTransform
    return transform.expand(input)
  File "beam_extended/io/mongodbio.py", line 206, in expand
    return pcoll | iobase.Write(self._sink)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pvalue.py", line 111, in __or__
    return self.pipeline.apply(ptransform, self)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 504, in apply
    pvalueish_result = self.runner.apply(transform, pvalueish)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 193, in apply
    return m(transform, input)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 199, in apply_PTransform
    return transform.expand(input)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/iobase.py", line 959, in expand
    return pcoll | WriteImpl(self.sink)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pvalue.py", line 111, in __or__
    return self.pipeline.apply(ptransform, self)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 504, in apply
    pvalueish_result = self.runner.apply(transform, pvalueish)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 193, in apply
    return m(transform, input)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 199, in apply_PTransform
    return transform.expand(input)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/iobase.py", line 1007, in expand
    AsIter(write_result_coll))
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/core.py", line 998, in FlatMap
    pardo = ParDo(CallableWrapperDoFn(fn), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/core.py", line 838, in __init__
    super(ParDo, self).__init__(fn, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py", line 639, in __init__
    self.args = pickler.loads(pickler.dumps(self.args))
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 216, in dumps
    s = dill.dumps(o)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 293, in dumps
    dump(obj, file, protocol, byref, fmode, recurse)#, strictio)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 286, in dump
    pik.dump(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 606, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 639, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 184, in new_save_module_dict
    return old_save_module_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 184, in new_save_module_dict
    return old_save_module_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 184, in new_save_module_dict
    return old_save_module_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 184, in new_save_module_dict
    return old_save_module_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 692, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 184, in new_save_module_dict
    return old_save_module_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 731, in save_inst
    save(stuff)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 184, in new_save_module_dict
    return old_save_module_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 184, in new_save_module_dict
    return old_save_module_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/home/pascal/Wks/GitHub/PEAT-AI/beam-extended/sdks/python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 313, in save
    (t.__name__, obj))
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle 'poll' object: <select.poll object at 0x7fdb82f95ab0>
```

Comment: Found the first issue, which was due to: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/iobase.py#L672

Comment: Do you store any non-picklable state when initializing a source, sink, or DoFn object ? These Beam objects get serialized by Dataflow runner during job submission so you won't be able to store non-picklable state.

Comment: @chamikara, well, yes, when I am initializing the Writer, I am saving a reference to the collection where I want to save my data which is constructed from a MongoClient object which is sadly using a poll object which is not pickable... But I don't know how to avoid this... `pymongo` is the de facto package use to access mongoDB with python, and I am not really sure that we can avoid it for such implementation. I don't have time/energy/skills to start a new python implementation for mongoDB for this alone on a side project. project...

Comment: and also, an issue on the Dill python package that Apache Beam is using to do the pickling stuff: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/207